# htaccess redirect with a pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Using the `.htaccess`, I want to 301 redirect all the requests that end with `default.aspx` to the version without it. Like:

```
https://example.com/pagename/default.aspx
```

will be redirected to

```
https://example.com/pagename/
```

How can I do that?

I tried to use the `rewriteRule` but it is throwing a 500 error. Here is my snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/default\.aspx$ $1 [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what 500 error you got? can you check your apache error log for more detail?

Comment: `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /site/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1248`

Comment: that's the reason why you got 500 error, not related to RewriteRule problem

Comment: Thank you @Ben. I asked question in the [WordPress development forum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292274/htaccess-redirect-throws-an-error-php-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp).